# What is the TryExec field in .desktop files?

Tags: .desktop

I have searched a great deal and have been unable to find an answer to this. What does the `TryExec` field do in .desktop files? How does it differ from the `Exec` field?

Comment: [_Path to an executable file on disk used to determine if the program is actually installed. If the path is not an absolute path, the file is looked up in the $PATH environment variable. If the file is not present or if it is not executable, the entry may be ignored (not be used in menus, for example)._](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

Comment: @don_cissti: you should add this as an answer. For completeness add the link to https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/.

Answer (score 30):

According to [standards.freedesktop.org](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#idm140676267060848), the `TryExec` entry takes the following:

> Path to an executable file on disk used to determine if the program is actually installed. If the path is not an absolute path, the file is looked up in the $PATH environment variable. If the file is not present or if it is not executable, the entry may be ignored (not be used in menus, for example).

[Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html#idm140434866991296) states:

> A .desktop file with a non-empty TryExec field MUST NOT be autostarted if the value of the TryExec key does NOT match with an installed executable program.

Unlike `Exec` and despite the similar name, `TryExec` does not actually execute it's value.

Comment: And what `$PATH` is used? It seems that changes to the `$PATH` made by the user's shell config are not included.

Comment: I ran into an issue. I hope this saves someone else time. I don't think the TryExec path can be a symlink. I wasn't seeing my .desktop file show up in the list of sessions for my greeter and as soon as I changed my TryExec from a symlink to a direct copy of the file, it worked.

Comment: @ntc2 the `$PATH` that is passed to the application launcher's environment. If you changed the PATH of your shell, it might affect the launcher's environment if you did it early enough, (e.g. in .bash_login in the case of bash), or similar for other shells. If you're doing it in .bashrc, probably not? You'll have to look up the config loading specifics of your shell.