# Desktop not being picked up

Tags: fedora, cinnamon, session, lightdm, optimus

I wanted to configure a Cinnamon desktop that used `optirun` so I created a new `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

However, this option is not being shown as a desktop on the login screen. I've tried `killall lightdm` and also restarting the computer.

What do I need to do to get my new desktop to come up as an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the TryExec field in .desktop files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263922/what-is-the-tryexec-field-in-desktop-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because I had a command with args in `Exec` and `TryExec` rather than the path to a script.

Reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/263922/67045) shows that `TryExec` isn't actually executed and it is just used to decide whether to offer this desktop, so that could be the reason it didn't work for me to start with.

Solution: Ensure `TryExec` and possibly `Exec` point to actual script file paths rather than stating an executable with args.